# Weird unknown type name issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

So I have this -

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "RateView.h"

@interface BasicCardViewController : UIViewController<RateViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property(copy, nonatomic)NSString *message;
@property(atomic)NSInteger rating;


@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet RateView *rateView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ratingLabel;


@end
```

and this - in my RateView.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@class RateView;

@protocol RateViewDelegate
-(void)rateView:(RateView *)rateView ratingDidChange:(float)rating;
@end



@interface RateView : UIView

@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImage* fullSelectedStar;
@property(strong,nonatomic)UIImage* notSelectedStar;
@property(strong, nonatomic)UIImage* halfSelectedStar;
@property (assign, nonatomic)float rating;
@property(assign) BOOL editable;
@property (strong) NSMutableArray* imageViews;
@property(assign,nonatomic) int maxRating;
@property(assign) int midMargin;
@property(assign)int leftMargin;
@property (assign) CGSize minImageSize;
@property (assign) id <RateViewDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

But I get two errors -

1.Cannot find protocol declaration for 'TooviaRateViewDelegate'
2.Unknown type name "RateView"

I've tried to clean, and I've verified that the files are where they should be (their filepaths are to the project).

Why is this happening?

Edit - my AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SearchViewController.h"

@interface TooviaAppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property NSOperationQueue *queue;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDictionary *userProfile;
@property (strong, nonatomic) SearchViewController *searchViewController;

- (NSOperationQueue*) getOperationQueue;
- (id)getSettings:(NSString *)keyPath;
- (void) saveCookies;


@end
```

There are also issues in my SearchViewController

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "BasicCardViewController.h"

@interface SearchViewController : UIViewController
    <UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
- (IBAction)searchButtonClicked:(UIButton *)sender;
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *resultTable;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *searchBar;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *resultsTuples;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *searchButton;
@property (copy, nonatomic) NSArray *controllers;
@property(strong,nonatomic)BasicCardViewController *detailController;
```

Comment: What's in your AppDelegate.h?

Comment: posting that right now

Comment: ohhh found it - I was importing app delegate.h in RateView where I didn't need it and I guess that was causing some circular dependency issue?

Comment: That's what I was thinking also.

Answer (score 0):

Delegate and data source properties are usually marked as weak for the object graph management reasons described earlier, in [“Avoid Strong Reference Cycles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html).”